# ssh -X with cygwin on Windows: "Unable to access the X Display"

Tags: python, windows, ssh, matplotlib, cygwin

I'm on a windows machine, trying to run a python program on my lab's server, and would like to be able to see the output plots it produces. Here is what I type to try:

```
ssh –X user@server
python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use(‘WX’)
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
mp.figure()
```

The figure doesn't show up, and I get this error:

```
"Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?"
```

Does anyone know how to make this work, or if it's even possible on a windows machine? Otherwise, any recommendations on how to get a look at the output data? I feel like this should be a very basic functionality, but I haven't found any solutions online yet and no one else in my lab uses windows.

Comment: Do you have an X server installed?

Comment: And if you have an X server installed, have you actually started it. Since you're using Cygwin, you might have a menu item `Cygwin-X -> XWin Server` that you need to run first...

Comment: voted to move to [su]. nothing actually to do with python

Comment: Or maybe [sf] ? Putty's support for SSH and X is pretty straingforward, check "enable X11 forwarding" in the SSH options.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have X forwarding set up and have the cygwin X server installed and running.

First, install the cygwin X server using cygwin's setup.exe.  Then, start it by typing `startxwin` in a cygwin shell.  Then try your ssh again.  If it still doesn't work, try `ssh -Y user@server`.

If it still doesn't work, you should make sure it's enabled in your ssh config: `/etc/ssh_config`

Look for the option `ForwardX11` and enable it.